# duplicated symbols dynamic loading

Tags: linker, dlopen

I have two dynamic libraries, a.so and b.so. Both libraries contain a function f() with different code in each library. This function is called in each library from another function, ga() and gb().

I also have an executable program that loads dynamically these two libraries using dlopen(). This program calls ga() and gb() at some point. What function f() would be executed in each case?

This is all C code, so f() should be the same symbol in both a.so and b.so.

Answer (score 3):

> What function f() would be executed in each case?

It *depends*.

If you are on a usual UNIX-like system, and you didn't use any special flags while compiling or linking `a.so` and `b.so`, and `f()` is a global (i.e. *not* a `static` function), then the `f` from whichever shared library was `dlopen`ed first is the one that will be called, assuming `RTLD_GLOBAL` flag was used in `dlopen`.

This answer changes when you use `-fvisibility=hidden` at compile time, or `-Bsymbolic` at link time, or use a linker script to restrict visibility of `f` or a linker version script to assign different symbol versions to the two instances, or with `RTLD_LOCAL`, or ... (I am sure I am missing more ways to change the behavior).

Comment: No special flags were used for compilation. However, I simplified the question a bit. Actually, this gets messy because what is duplicated is Ada code, which for me is more obscure.